# Make an object not cast a shadow in eevee

Tags: eevee-render-engine, shadows

Is there a way to make a single object not cast shadows in Eevee?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, by setting a material to an object and in properties panel choose *Materials > Setting > Shadow Mode : **None***

[image: Shadow Mode - None]

Comment: This doesn't work for me. What could be the reason?

Comment: @TimSim Not sure, I use it in `2.80` version. `2.81` and above version may have different behavior. Also, this is a strange way to disable shadow in my opinion. There might be some limitation that I don't know. And the ambient occlusion shadow won't been disabled as well.